# indexPathForCell: returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a table view and this method to find the indexPath of a subview of one of its cells...

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathContainingView:(UIView *)view {
    while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]]) {
        view = view.superview;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    return (cell)? [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell] : nil;
}
```

I call with a subview of the topmost cell (which is visible, the table view has **not** been scrolled), and, with a breakpoint on the `return` line, I get this perplexing result in lldb...

[image]

`cell` looks good.  The cell's table view matches my `tableView` (there's some intermediate `UITableViewWrapperView` as the direct superview).  But see how `indexPathForCell:` returns nil?  I am certain that the cell is visible.

I don't think it matters, but the subview of the `cell` I begin with is a `UICollectionView`, and I'm calling this on the collection view's datasource methods.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** more context...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // do stuff to setup the cell
    // now reload the collection view that it contains
    UICollectionView *collectionView = (UICollectionView *)[cell viewWithTag:33];
    [collectionView reloadData];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathContainingView:collectionView];
    return // get my model from the index path and return the count of an array it contains
    // but here's the problem.  index path is nil here
}
```

Comment: Is the cell currently visible in the table view? You only get an index path if the cell is visible.

Comment: Who is calling `indexPathContainingView` and when?

Comment: @rmaddy - yes, the cell is the first cell in an unscrolled table.

Comment: @shallowThought it's called elsewhere from the same vc, in the datasource method of a collection view contained by the cell.  To get that collection view's count, I need to know the index path (so I can look up the right thing in the table view's datasource).

Comment: And the cell was properly dequeued from the table view?

Comment: @rmaddy - I believe so.  Edited to show more context.

Comment: As a rule, almost any time you find yourself walking the view hierarchy, you are probably using the wrong approach. This can be fragile as new versions of iOS can interpose new views in the hierarchy without warning and it also means you are tightly coupling your view with your data model. `viewWithTag` is icky too. You should use a custom cell class and that exposes a property for the collection view. Also since cells are reused you shouldn't rely on getting a cell to get back to your model. Your view controller should already have access to it

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks, but I'm not sure I understand the solution you're suggesting.  If I create a cell subclass that has an outlet to a collection view, how can I get from a collection view datasource method to the indexPath table view?

Comment: @Paulw11, please note that I'm not trying to get my model from the cell, I'm trying to get an indexPath.  I've got the model (array) in the view controller as you suggest, but I don't know the index into that array unless I have an indexPath.

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand now; You want your view controller to be the `UICollectionViewDatasource` for all of collection views which are in cells.  If it were me, I would make the UITableViewCell subclass the collection view data source and simply assign the appropriate array to the a property of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You can use a setter on this property to reload the collection view to handle cell reuse

Comment: @Paulw11 - ok.  thanks, that's the first workaround idea that makes sense.  cherry on top would be even a plausible theory about why the posted code doesn't work.  just forgetting how/why we got to that point, the strangeness is plain as day in the lldb:  the cell is visible, it's clearly in the table, why wouldn't that indexPathForCell method do the right thing?

Comment: The most obvious answer is that *that* cell isn't currently visible on *that* tableview.  You don't know at what point in the tableview layout process your collection view datasource method was called.  I suspect that the tableview doesn't currently consider that cell visible.  As I said, any time you find yourself walking the view hierarchy, you are probably using the wrong approach; it is fragile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using storyboards and if you are willing to change the approach you are using a possible solution would be (And a cleaner solution in my opinion):

Drag an outlet of your `UICollectionView` inside your cell into the `UITableViewCell`. In your storyboard again set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the `UICollectionView` to your class by dragging the outlet. Of course you will have to use a custom `UITableViewCell`

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the `UITableView` set the tag of the the `UICollectionView` to be your `indexPath.row`. Now in your `numberOfItemsInSection` you can access the `UICollectionView` tag property and it will contain the `indexPath.row` of the `UITableViewCell` you are trying to access and hence you can access your model.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // do stuff to setup the cell
    // now reload the collection view that it contains
    cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.collectionView reloadData];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// get my model from the index path and return the count of an array it contains
    Model *model = dataArray[collectionView.tag];

    return model.count;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand.  Can you suggest a reason why my approach doesn't work?  If my approach worked, I think it would be better than this suggestion (as much as I appreciate your help!!) because your idea relies on a custom class for the cell and (more importantly) kind of abuses the `tag` property to do mean something else.  Consider if I also had sections in the table, would I mask the tag integer into a section and a row?

Comment: But I do appreciate the thought.  I might be stuck with this if I cannot figure it out.  I sure wish @rmaddy could lend some perspective here.

Comment: Well you could simply do that by subclassing the `UICollectionView` to contain two properties to pass section and row. Sure i'll have a look! I had some queries about your approach :D. In the first line of your `indexPathContainingView`. you have written `[UITableViewCell self]` and shouldn't it be `[UITableViewCell class]`? 
And also check what is the `view.superView` coming out to be? Won't it be the `contentView` of the cell and not the cell itself? Try using `view.superView.superView`!

Comment: :-) Thanks!  Sending `self` and `class` to a Class are synonymous.  And you're right that there can be some intermediate superviews on the way up from the subview to the cell, but I run that in a loop until I get to the cell.  See the lldb output to prove I've found the cell and that the cell belongs to the table.

Comment: Oh well i had no idea about the `self` and `class` part! Well the only other probable cause i can come up with that may cause a issue is using the same variable name as the argument you are passing to assign the `view.superview` to! But apart from that I cannot possible figure out why your code won't work! Sorry!

Comment: Thanks very much for the help.  +1, and I'll mark correct if I end up doing this.

Comment: I'm calling this correct for suggesting a custom class.  Rather than adding any index path properties to anything, I added a model property to the cell (per @Paulw11 suggestion).

Comment: Well if you are iffy about using tags you could always just subclass your `UICollectionView` to contain two properties to pass `section` and `row` or use an extension :).